# Why does tensorflow take more GPU RAM than the model file?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensorflow model saved as a protocol buffer format as `model.pb` which is `184 MB`. When I load it using a session, I see that the process hogs `11 GB` of GPU RAM. Why is that?

Comment: For one thing, by default TF allocates (almost) the whole GPU memory when you create a session, regardless of how much you actually need for the model (This makes memory management more efficient). Look up "enable GPU memory growth". For another, protobuf file doesn't represent the in-RAM weight of the model, but only the parameters saved. You still need, for example, input, output & intermediate buffers (& a whole bunch of other stuff, this is just an example to make the point), so yeah, expect your in-RAM size to be bigger. It's normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tensorflow uses all the GPU memory by default to minimize memory fragmentation (see the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu#allowing_gpu_memory_growth)). You can prevent this behavior by using the allow_growth config option:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = tf.Session(config=config, ...)
```